# Reactor Spring WebFlux: Explain please difference between last() and takeLast() methods

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor, spring5

Can anybody explain me difference between last() and takeLast() methods ?
As documentation tell:

**last()** - Emit the last element observed before complete signal as a Mono, or emit NoSuchElementException error if the source was empty. For a passive version use takeLast(int)

**takeLast()** - Emit the last N values this Flux emitted before its completion.

As for me it's the same.
I can not understand the differences.
Can someone explain me with a simple example?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kirill,

`takeLast(int n)` accepts integer indicating how many elements should be left in the stream
Example:

```
Flux.just(1, 2, 3, 4)
        .takeLast(3)
        .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Will result with

> 234

Meanwhile, `last()` method is only about the very last emitted element.

```
Flux.just(1, 2, 3, 4)
        .last()
        .subscribe(System.out::print);
```

The output is

> 4

---

Conclusion: `takeLast(1)` equals to `last()`

Comment: "Conclusion: takeLast(1) equals to last()"  this is not true when the flux is empty,  last() will fail, while takeLast will just return a new empty flux